# How can I use Count Command

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, crystal-reports-xi

```
SELECT        EMP_MASTER.EMP_NAME, SF_STR.SFS_NAME, SFT_MAS.TER_NAME
FROM            SF_STR INNER JOIN
                     EMP_MASTER ON SF_STR.SFS_CODE = EMP_MASTER.CMI_RT_SFS_CODE AND SF_STR.SFS_CODE = EMP_MASTER.CMI_TPC_SFS_CODE AND 
                     SF_STR.SFS_CODE = EMP_MASTER.E_SFS_CODE INNER JOIN
                     SFT_MAS ON SF_STR.SFS_CODE = SFT_MAS.SFS_CODE CROSS JOIN
                     DCR_LD INNER JOIN
                     DR_MAS ON DCR_LD.DR_CODE = DR_MAS.DR_CODE
```

Comment: Hey Thiru, can you please rephrase what you want and follow the standards to ask a question in this forum

Comment: Please read [ask] a good question and follow the forum guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to simply add the count to all the fields?

```
SELECT        count(*)
FROM            SF_STR INNER JOIN
                 EMP_MASTER ON SF_STR.SFS_CODE = EMP_MASTER.CMI_RT_SFS_CODE 
AND SF_STR.SFS_CODE = EMP_MASTER.CMI_TPC_SFS_CODE AND 
                 SF_STR.SFS_CODE = EMP_MASTER.E_SFS_CODE INNER JOIN
                 SFT_MAS ON SF_STR.SFS_CODE = SFT_MAS.SFS_CODE CROSS JOIN
                 DCR_LD INNER JOIN
                 DR_MAS ON DCR_LD.DR_CODE = DR_MAS.DR_CODE
```